# How can we set DateAndTime at Ascending in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Hi i am new for ios and i am integrating my app with services and i am getting here trip creation TimeandDate values and storing that values one separate Array and also i am getting pickUpAdress values from services and storing them one separate arrayList

After storing in arrayList i am set date values at "Ascending" order in my tableList

after set "Ascending"  when i display them in tableList both array-list data they are mismatching to one another please help me how can i resolve this problem how can i set my Adrress array values for matching to related DateandTimes

### code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder;
    NSArray * ToBeReadyTimeArray1;
    NSMutableArray * ToBeReadyTimeArray ,*finalToBeReadyTimeArray,*AdressArray;
    UITableView * MaintableView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ToBeReadyTimeArray1 = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    ToBeReadyTimeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"02/17/2016",@"03/13/2016",@"04/18/2016",@"05/21/2016", nil];

    finalToBeReadyTimeArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    AdressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Adress1",@"Adress2",@"Adress3",@"Adress4", nil];

    //Arange Date formate At Assending order:-

    sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
    ToBeReadyTimeArray1 =  [ToBeReadyTimeArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

    for (NSString *dte in ToBeReadyTimeArray1){

        NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [aDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

        [aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSDate * parsed = [aDateFormatter dateFromString:dte];
        [aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
        NSString *aFormattedElapsedTime = [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:parsed];
        NSLog(@"tobe Ready time %@",aFormattedElapsedTime);
        [finalToBeReadyTimeArray addObject:aFormattedElapsedTime];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to list pick up times / address with some sorted order. If that's so, i would have created a `NSArray` of Booking or Trip models which would contain the information as Address `(NSString *)` and PickUpTime `(NSDate *)` and then would have implemented a sorting method using the property as variable key.

In my case, I implemented an array of booking models which has pickUpTime and address.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *pickUpTime; // Timestamp instead of NSDate ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
```

I implemented a category method for NSArray. Please note that sort order enumerations are manually implemented.

```
+ (NSArray *)sortArray:(NSArray *)unSortedArray byOrder:(SortOrder)sortOrder usingVariableKey:(NSString *)variableKey {
    NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray array];
    BOOL isAscendingOrder = NO;


    if (sortOrder == SortOrderAscending) {
        isAscendingOrder = YES;
    }

    if (unSortedArray) {
        NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:variableKey ascending:isAscendingOrder];
        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];
        sortedArray = [[unSortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] mutableCopy];
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Then, i invoked the following ...

```
    // Here, resultMutableArray is a mutable array of booking models ...
    NSArray *resultArray = [NSArray sortArray:[resultMutableArray copy] byOrder:SortOrderDescending usingVariableKey:@"pickUpTime"];
```